# Method to check if number is contained in ArrayList will not work, NullPointerExcepton. Can you use ArrayList method inside a constructed method?

Tags: arraylist, null

This is a project I am working on and it is supposed to take input from the user then which is an area code then see if it is contained in a array list. My method that I have created will not work in another class and I am not sure why, it is returning a NullPointerException.

The NullPointerException is shown at this line of code: *if (mountainTime.contains(input))*

**This is the class with methods**

```
    package finalPro;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Final 
{


    public Final()
    {
        input = 0;
        timezone = 0;
    }

    public void checkIfTrue(int y)
    {
        input = y;

        if (mountainTime.contains(input))
        {
            timezone = 1;

        }
        else
            timezone = 0;
        System.out.println(timezone);
    }

    public int getZone()
    {
        return timezone;
    }

public ArrayList<Integer> mountainTime;
private int input;

private int timezone;

}
```

**Here is test class**

```
package finalPro;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FinalLogic 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

            ArrayList<Integer> mountainTime = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            mountainTime.add(480);
            mountainTime.add(602);
            mountainTime.add(623);          //Arizona area codes
            mountainTime.add(928);
            mountainTime.add(520);

            mountainTime.add(303);
            mountainTime.add(719);          //Colorado
            mountainTime.add(720);
            mountainTime.add(970);

            mountainTime.add(406);          //Montana

            mountainTime.add(505);          //New Mexico
            mountainTime.add(575);

            mountainTime.add(385);
            mountainTime.add(435);          //Utah
            mountainTime.add(801);

            mountainTime.add(307);          //Wyoming



        Final myMap = new Final();

        {

            String x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number: ");

            int input = Integer.parseInt(x);

            myMap.checkIfTrue(input);

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: well, because you have not intialized `public ArrayList<Integer> mountainTime;`. All the steps that you wrote in `main` method for initalizing `mountainTime`, you can put them in constructor `public Final()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already tried moving around the mountainTime steps to the other class and the same error exists either way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it's not too late, I haven't done anything special to fix your code, just some movement of code,
Removed the initialization logic from class `FinalLogic` to `Final` class .(btw `Final` name is not really good, you might be aware `final` is reserved word in Java. Although your name is case sensitive but still)

```
package finalPro;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FinalLogic {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Final myMap = new Final();
    String x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number: ");
    int input = Integer.parseInt(x);
    myMap.checkIfTrue(input);

}
}
```

And here is your class `Final`

```
package finalPro;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Final {

public Final() {
    input = 0;
    timezone = 0;
    // moved all initialization logic to constructor
    mountainTime = new ArrayList<>();
    mountainTime.add(480);
    mountainTime.add(602);
    mountainTime.add(623); // Arizona area codes
    mountainTime.add(928);
    mountainTime.add(520);
    mountainTime.add(303);
    mountainTime.add(719); // Colorado
    mountainTime.add(720);
    mountainTime.add(970);
    mountainTime.add(406); // Montana
    mountainTime.add(505); // New Mexico
    mountainTime.add(575);
    mountainTime.add(385);
    mountainTime.add(435); // Utah
    mountainTime.add(801);
    mountainTime.add(307); // Wyoming
}

public void checkIfTrue(int y) {
    input = y;

    if (mountainTime.contains(input)) {
        timezone = 1;

    } else
        timezone = 0;
    System.out.println(timezone);
}

public int getZone() {
    return timezone;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> mountainTime;
private int input;
private int timezone;

}
```

I tried in my workspace, it gives no NPE, Hope it helps.

Comment: Nope, not too late. This seemed to work out my kink, even though I am pretty sure I already tried this. Really appreciate the help!